# Forse a .class :hover state

Tags: javascript, hover, mousehover

What I want to do is that when someone enter the image that forces a `:hover` state to the `.right` class below the image itself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
$(document).on('mouseover','img',function(){$(".right").hover();return false;});
```

```css
.image{float:left;display:inline-block;width:20vw;margin:20px}
img{width:100%;cursor:pointer}
.right:after{content:"buy"}
.right:hover:after{content:"£2.50"}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=image>
<img src="https://sites.psu.edu/siowfa16/files/2016/10/YeDYzSR-10apkm4.png" alt="smile">
<div class=right></div>
</div>
<div class=image>
<img src="https://sites.psu.edu/siowfa16/files/2016/10/YeDYzSR-10apkm4.png" alt="smile">
<div class=right></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are missing quotes for your class names, use `<div class="image">`

Comment: a better option would be to add and remove a class that does the hover function instead of playing around with pseudo classes.

Comment: @ArunKumar those are not mandatory, right?

Comment: @Federico mandatory for valid HTML

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('mouseover','img',function(event){
$(".right").removeClass("hover");
$(this).parent().find(".right").toggleClass("hover");
return true;
});
```

```css
.image{float:left;display:inline-block;width:20vw;margin:20px}
img{width:100%;cursor:pointer}
.right:after{content:"buy"}
.right:hover:after{content:"£2.50"}
.hover:after{content:"£2.50"}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image">
<img src="https://sites.psu.edu/siowfa16/files/2016/10/YeDYzSR-10apkm4.png" alt="smile">
<div class="right"></div>
</div>
<div class="image">
<img src="https://sites.psu.edu/siowfa16/files/2016/10/YeDYzSR-10apkm4.png" alt="smile">
<div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Try this . Define your mouse over effect in a class using CSS then toggle that class using jquery.

Comment: it's almost what I want the thing is that I want just the class below the image to have that state. I'm trying to work with .closest but nothing yet.

Comment: @Federico Let me try.